# Game Object deletes itself without having Destroy() in the script

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

I am creating a Space simultation in Unity using Newtons Law of gravitation and Centripetal force calculations to re-create the motion of the planets. Recently i have tried to implement realistic masses such as 3.285e+23 and i have converted them to managable numbers using a massScale 1e-24f. but since implementing these new masses and converting them, the smaller planet of the three has started deleting itself shortly after runtime without any error being thrown. I will also add that i dont have any sort of Destroy Line in my code either.

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlanetVelocity : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Gravity _gravity;
        public float v;
        public bool debugBool;
        public GameObject Sun;
        private Rigidbody rb;
        private Vector3 dif;

        public static List<GameObject> AllPlanets;
        private const float distScale = 1e-7f;
        private const float massScale = 1e-24f;
        private const float gravity = 6.674e-11f;
    
        public float mass = 5.972e24f;
    
        private Vector3 motion;
    
        [Header("Orbital Data")]
        public float velocity = 29.8f;
        public float distance = 148900000f;
    
    //TODO: Convert weight units to KG and use realistic weights for planetary bodies
    /*Calculate velocity using v = sqrt[(G M )/r]*/
    /*Get the Planet to look at the sun*/
    /*Apply V to the transform.right of the planet to have perpendicular motion*/
    
    void Start()
    {
        _gravity = FindObjectOfType<Gravity>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.mass = mass * massScale;
    }

    void DebugClass()
    {
        if(debugBool)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Mass Scale {rb.mass}");
            //Debug.DrawRay(gameObject.transform.position, motion, Color.red);
           // Debug.Log($"Calculated Velocity = {v} Difference {dif} Motion {motion}");
        }
    }
    void ObjectLook()
    {
        transform.LookAt(Sun.transform);
    }

    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        DebugClass();
        ObjectLook();
        Vector3 sunPos = new Vector3(Sun.transform.position.x, Sun.transform.position.y, Sun.transform.position.z);
        Vector3 planetPos = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y,
            gameObject.transform.position.z);

        Vector3 dif = sunPos - planetPos;
        float r = dif.sqrMagnitude;

        v = Mathf.Sqrt(_gravity.f * rb.mass) / r;
        //v = Mathf.Sqrt(_gravity.G * rb.mass / r ) ;

        Vector3 motion = transform.up * v;
        if (gameObject.transform.position.x > 0 && gameObject.transform.position.y > 0)
        {
            motion.x = Math.Abs(motion.x);
            motion.y = -Math.Abs(motion.y);
        }

        if (gameObject.transform.position.x > 0 && gameObject.transform.position.y < 0)
        {
            motion.x = -Math.Abs(motion.x);
            motion.y = -Math.Abs(motion.y);
        }

        rb.velocity = motion;
        
    }
}
```

and here is my script controlling gravitational pull towards the sun, based off of what game objects are withing the sphere collider range of the sun.

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour
    {
    
        public float f; //force

        private const float massScale = 1e-24f;
     
    
        public float mass = 1.989e+30f;
    
        public float G = 6.674e-11f; //Gravitational Constant
    
        private Rigidbody m1;//Mass 1 The Sun ( this Game Object)
        private Rigidbody m2;//Mass 2 Planet
        private Vector3 r1;
    
        public Vector3 FORCE;
    
        public bool debugBool;

    void Start()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 50f;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        m1 = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        m1.mass = mass * massScale;
    }

    private void DebugClass()
    {
        if (debugBool)
        {
            Debug.Log(m2.velocity); 
            Debug.Log("TRIGGERED");
            Debug.Log($"r1 {r1.normalized} FORCE {FORCE}");
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        DebugClass();
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        //declares rigidbody locally
        Rigidbody m2;
        //assigns other objects rigidbody to m2
        m2 = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        
        // get sun position
        Vector3 Sun = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z);
        // planet
        Vector3 otherPlanet = new Vector3(other.gameObject.transform.position.x, other.gameObject.transform.position.y, other.gameObject.transform.position.z);
      
       
        //Difference between each object
        Vector3 r1 = Sun - otherPlanet;
     
        //Difference between each object squared
        float r2 = r1.sqrMagnitude;
        float distance = r1.magnitude;
        
        ///<summary>
        /// Calculates Force by Mutliplying Gravitational
        /// constant by the mass of each object divided 
        /// by the distance between each object squared
        /// <summary>
        f = G * m1.mass * m2.mass / r2;
        
        
        //Assigns the value r1 normalized between 0 and 1
        //multiplied by F independent of frames per second
        Vector3 FORCE = r1.normalized * f * Time.deltaTime;
        
        // Adds force to the other game objects rigidbody using the FORCE vector
        // Using the Force force mode
        m2.AddForce(FORCE);

    }
}
```

Comment: Unity doesn't simply destroy objects randomly .. somewhere something has to be calling `Destroy`! In order to find out you can use a simple trick: On your object put a class like `public class WhatDestroyesMe : MonoBehaviour { private void OnDestroy () { Debug.LogError("I WAS JUST DESTROYED!!!!"); } }` then you can see in the stacktrace in the console what exactly lead to this object being destroyed. Additionally you can then set a breakpoint at the debug line and see when exactly this happens while [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

Comment: Or maybe your object isn't even destroyed but just sucked into the sun or kicked out of visibility? Have you checked the hierarchy?

Comment: Hi Derhugo Thank you for replying! when i check the heirarchy the game object actually gets removed from it with no destroy on load game object appearing which leads me to think unity is destroying the object without being told to! i will also add that the object reappears after i stop the game, i will use your debug method to see if it is being destroyed and add another comment here!

Comment: Okay so apparently it is being destroyed, but i have nothing in my code telling it to be destroyed, so this is where my confusion lies, i will edit my post with a snapshot of what my ide has identified on the breakpoint

Comment: here is the imgur for the IDE results

https://imgur.com/a/31WMKVh

Comment: It doesn't look destroyed to me but inactive .. what I ment was in the console click on the according `I WAS JUST DESTROYED` log message and in the bottom part you can see all details and from where exactly the destroy came ... You can move up the separator line if it is not showing all lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues with extremely small float numbers on my Rigidbody transform and thus unity was deactivating the game object before it overflowed, my solution was to multiply the physic calculations i used by a 'PhysicsMultiplier' and this solved my issues completely